# Reduce image size to left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following effect using CSS or CSS3 only:

The arrow in the diagram represents a picture.  As the browser resizes, I want the picture to move to the left without touching the text and the picture does not resizes.  So basically in this case, the arrow gets shorter as the browser resizes, so the remainder of the image is still there just hidden so that it can come back when I maximize the window again.  Is this possible with CSS or CSS3 only?

```
[-------------------]
[                   ]
[ text -----------> ]  <--- Web Page
[                   ]
[                   ]
[                   ]
[                   ]
[-------------------]

[---------------]
[               ]
[ text -------> ]  <--- Web Page
[               ]
[               ]
[               ]
[               ]
[---------------]
```

Comment: Does the text get squeezed when the window gets smaller or does it stay at a fixed width?

Comment: Have you tinkered with `width: 100%; min-width: 500px;`?

Comment: More specifically, `min-width` http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/90suyunt/

Comment: Text stays fixed width

Comment: Evan, your image doesn't shift to the left, it just shrinks and becomes scrollable, this is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I could do:
http://jsfiddle.net/rmadhuram/czpnyn2x/

I could get the picture move left by positioning the background image, but the side effect is that the height of the right column had to be fixed.

```
.image {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/The_2010_Perseids_over_the_VLT.jpg/1920px-The_2010_Perseids_over_the_VLT.jpg');
    background-position: right top;
    height: 1280px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for, I'll test tomorrow when I'm back from work, ran out of time today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe `position: fixed` might be what you are looking for ( [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f658L0xt/)).